# OSM place name translation

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openstreetmap, nominatim

I'm doing a project in OSM. My purpose is to translate the place names into any other local languages.  Is there any tools which helps for this purpose other than Nomino which can be implemented faster?

`Does JOSM supports translation of the place names in OSM??`

Comment: Did you considered to use Wikidata in combination with OSM? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Collaboration_with_Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

You might checkout the Add-tags JOSM plugin: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/RemoteControl/Add-tags